# How fill label inside TemplateColumn of Telerik RadGrid in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, telerik, radgrid

Here is my RadGrid aspx :

```
   <telerik:RadGrid ID="grd_transactions" runat="server" GroupPanelPosition="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <GroupingSettings CollapseAllTooltip="Collapse all groups"></GroupingSettings>
        <MasterTableView>
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter TemplateColumn_Type column" HeaderText="Type" UniqueName="TemplateColumn_Type">
                    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium" Width="100px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_Type" runat="server" Text="lbl_Type"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter TemplateColumn_Date_Time_UTC_GMT column" HeaderText="Date &amp; Time (UTC/GMT)" UniqueName="TemplateColumn_Date_Time_UTC_GMT">
                    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium" Width="200px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_Date_Time_UTC_GMT" runat="server" Text="lbl_Date_Time_UTC_GMT"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter TemplateColumn_BTC_Investment_Address column" HeaderText="BTC Investment Address" UniqueName="TemplateColumn_BTC_Investment_Address">
                    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium" Width="600px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_BTC_Investment_Address" runat="server" Text="lbl_BTC_Investment_Address"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter TemplateColumn_Deposit_Amount column" HeaderText="Deposit Amount" UniqueName="TemplateColumn_Deposit_Amount">
                    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium" Width="150px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_Deposit_Amount" runat="server" Text="lbl_Deposit_Amount"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter TemplateColumn_Payout_Amount column" HeaderText="Payout Amount" UniqueName="TemplateColumn_Payout_Amount">
                    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium" Width="150px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_Payout_Amount" runat="server" Text="lbl_Payout_Amount"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter TemplateColumn_Status column" HeaderText="Status" UniqueName="TemplateColumn_Status">
                    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium" Width="150px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_Status" runat="server" Text="lbl_Status"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            </Columns>
        </MasterTableView>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Now in code behind i want to fill those labels inside TemplateColumns like this :

```
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Date &amp; Time (UTC/GMT)", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("BTC Investment Address", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Deposit Amount", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Payout Amount", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(string));
    table.Rows.Add("1", "2", "3", "4" ,"5", "6");
    table.Rows.Add("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6");
    table.Rows.Add("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6");
    table.Rows.Add("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6");
    table.Rows.Add("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6");
    grd_transactions.DataSource = table;
    grd_transactions.DataBind();
```

Here is the wrong output :

[image: output]

How can i access those labels & fill them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not need custom labels, you can change GridTemplateColumn to GridBoundColumn.
First column as for an example:

```
  <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type" UniqueName="TemplateColumn_Type"  ItemStyle-Width="100px" >
    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium" Width="100px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
```

You just need to have same value in DataField of radgrid column and column name in Datatable.
"Type" In this case.

If you want to use GridTemplateColumn, then change text value and use DataBinder like this:

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter TemplateColumn_Type column" HeaderText="Type" UniqueName="TemplateColumn_Type">
                    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium" Width="100px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_Type" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Type")%>' ></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Apply on rest columns.